# problem with runnig GROMACS in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, tar

I am new to Ubuntu. I have just installed gromacs (version 5.1.2) on my Ubuntu (16.04) by using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gromacs
```

But I can not run the program. The gmx file is in  `/usr/bin`
 when I use the command:

```
source /usr/bin/gmx
bash: source: /usr/bin/gmx: cannot execute binary file
```

My computer Processor type is x86-64. 
 I have also tried by installing gromacs manually from  http://www.gromacs.org/Downloads  and then I used command:

```
tar xfz gromacs-version.tar.gz
tar (child): gromacs-version.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

**I don't know what is the problem and how to solve it! I appreciate any advice.**

Comment: The first problem you are trying to `source` a binary file - you should just be running it (e.g. by simply typing `gmx` or possibly `gmx mdrun`). I don't recommend trying to install manually if you are that inexperienced.

Comment: I agree with steeldriver's comment except that to run it you need to type the command: `gmx-mdrun` instead, but before you run anything do two things: 1. Run `man gromacs` 2.  `sudo apt install gromacs-data` will give you some data to test the app.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. At the first I installed gromacs from an instruction that I  found in one of the YouTube clips. Apparently I had a successful installation but when I wanted to run the program l had an error like you had:

```
bash:source: /usr/bin/gmx cannot execute binary
```

After a lot  search l understood that source of gromacs should be:

```
source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC
```

NOT

```
source/usr/bin/gmx
```

Finally l could solve my problem by using instruction of installation from gromacs site but before I  removed my Ubuntu and installed a new one.

This is an instruction that I used from this [link](http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Installation_Instructions_5.0).

**Quick and dirty installation**

- Get the latest version of your C and C++ compilers.
- Check that you have CMake version 2.8.8 or later.
- Get and unpack the latest version of the GROMACS tarball.
- Make a separate build directory and change to it.
- Run cmake with the path to the source as an argument
- Run make, make check, and make install

Or, as a sequence of commands to execute:

```
tar xfz gromacs-5.0.7.tar.gz
cd gromacs-5.0.7
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=ON -DREGRESSIONTEST_DOWNLOAD=ON
make
make check
sudo make install
source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC
```

This will download and build first the prerequisite FFT library followed by GROMACS. If you already have FFTW installed, you can remove that argument to cmake. Overall, this build of GROMACS will be correct and reasonably fast on the machine upon which cmake ran. If you want to get the maximum value for your hardware with GROMACS, you will have to read further. Sadly, the interactions of hardware, libraries, and compilers are only going to continue to get more complex.

Comment: please ask your own question

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried by installing gromacs manually from http://www.gromacs.org/Downloads and then I used command: `tar xfz gromacs-version.tar.gz` but again it doesnt work

Supposed that

- `gromacs-version.tar.gz` is a valid filename (older versions had names as `gromacs-5.1.4.tar.gz`, while versions of the GROMACS 2016 series follow the scheme `gromacs-2016.4.tar.gz`)
- the gzipped tar file is not corrupt
- you're in the right directory
- the directory where the archive resides is writable

`tar xfz gromacs-version.tar.gz` should unpack the file to a directory structure with the README, a bunch of scripts and the source code.

Note that unpacking the `tar.gz` is just the first step in building GROMACS. At this stage, you are far from having a usable GROMACS system!

It can be advantageous to have a GROMACS installation tailored to your own system, particularly when the logs of runs using a GROMACS build installed via `apt` contain hints like

> Binary not matching hardware - you might be losing performance.
>   SIMD instructions most likely to fit this hardware: AVX2_256
>   SIMD instructions selected at GROMACS compile time: SSE2

However, I'm with `steeldriver` and `karel` on this: **Don't!**

---

Install GROMACS from the package manager and learn to use it before you start any optimizations!

As `steeldriver` and `karel` have already mentioned, `source gmx` will not get you anywhere, neither will `gmx` alone ;-)

Starting with version 5.0, all tools in GROMACS that were separate binaries in earlier versions, e.g. `pdb2gmx`, are now only accessible as `gmx` subcommands!

My suggestion is:

1. Use the GROMACS version from the repo.
2. Work through some recent tutorials based on GROMACS 5.0 (or later) to get familiar with the workflows. A really god point to start are the tutorials by [Justin A. Lemkul](http://www.bevanlab.biochem.vt.edu/Pages/Personal/justin/gmx-tutorials/lysozyme/index.html).